# Character Limit exceeded in Validation Rule

Tags: apex, formula, validation-rule

I Have Validation rules with below rule
**OR(Profile.name='Pname1',Profile.name='Pname',Profile.name='Pname3', and so on....)**
I have almost 100 profile names which i am not able to listed down in one validation rule.

workaround please. I have created 2 validation rules instead of one.
But is there any solution ,so i can use only one validation rule.
Please Suggest

Comment: Could you not just do profile.name != ?

Comment: I have total 250 profiles ,so if i used != still it will not work

Comment: How many profiles do you need to include versus exclude? Alternatively Is it an option to add a custom field on the user record and use that instead?

Comment: I have total 200 Profiles from which 90 profiles needs to be included and remaining needs to be excluded.Unfortunately cannot use custom fields because of some restrictions

Comment: is this possible if i create a custom label and used CONTAINS                                                                                                                 for ex: CONTAINS($Label . Profiles_name, text 2)  Here how can i compare..can you please complete formula if you can

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few different approaches that you could take here. These suggestions may be able to be combined.

**Option 1**

Consider using `$UserRole` instead of `$Profile`. This would benefit you if multiple profiles are covered by a single role

**Option 2**

Use the `CASE()` function to remove as much repetition as possible. This would look like

```
IF(
    CASE(Profile.Name,
        'PName1', 1,
        'PName2', 1,
        ...
        'PName90', 1,
        -1
    ) > 0,
    true,
    false
)
```

In this example, if the profile name was one of the 90 specified, the validation rule would trip, preventing the operation from occurring. It's easy enough to flip around so that the 90 specified profiles would be allowed to complete the operation.

**Option 3**

Handle this with a Hierarchy Custom Setting. It'd have at least one checkbox. Set the default value for the org to true or false, then add your 90 profiles, setting the value to the opposite of the default org value.

Assuming your Custom Setting is named `MyCustomSetting`, and your field is named `AllowOperation` you validation rule would become simply

```
$Setup.MyCustomSetting__c.AllowOperation__c
```

The downside of using a Custom Setting is that you would need to re-enter the data in any sandboxes you have (after creating or refreshing the sandbox, except for full copy sandboxes, and maybe partial copy sandboxes as well). You could use the DataLoader to manage this, but it is an extra step.

If you need to use this same profile-checking logic in multiple validation rules (and/or in apex or Visualforce pages), it may be worth it to go with the Custom Setting route.

If this is a one-off validation rule, I'd suggest trying to combine options 1 and 2.

Comment: is this possible using custom label? like  if(ISCHANGED(profile.name and contains(Customlable) then fire validation rule

Comment: It looks like this is possible in the form of `CONTAINS($Profile.Name, $Label.<label name>)`; however, the limit on the value of a custom label is 1000 characters, which is more restrictive than the character limit of validation rules. While it is possible to use multiple custom labels, this really isn't what that functionality was built to do. Trying to force a square peg through a round hole will only make your solution harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that can be used recently is by using Custom Permissions.

You can create custom permission, assign the permissions to the covered profiles and your Validation rule can be written from

```
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(CloseDate)))&&
ISCHANGED(CloseDate) &&
OR(Profile.name='Pname1',Profile.name='Pname',Profile.name='Pname3', and so on....)
```

to

```
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(CloseDate)))&&
ISCHANGED(CloseDate) &&
NOT($Permission.Permission_API_Name)
```

The custom permission is like adding a new checkbox in a profile. In this case the ability to pass the validation. In my example, I want to change the Close Date in an opportunity. I add the permission that can be named Can_Change_CloseDate to all profiles o user through Permission Set and using the merge field

```
$Permission.Can_Change_CloseDate
```